# GAM() error: unused argument(s) (bs = "ps", k = 8)?

Tags: r

After loading mgcv and running the below model - it returns the error below.. This code has worked in previous times (i.e. yesterday).  Any help with this would be much appreciated.

```
> aa1<-gam(Bin~s(Mud,bs="ps",k=8),family=binomial, gamma=1,data=Abaren)

Error in s(Mud, bs = "ps", k = 8) : unused argument(s) (bs = "ps", k = 8)
```

--

I'm now getting the error below.. This all seems rather strange given the fact all of this code was running perfectly just two days ago..

```
## UQ Abundance only data (i.e. positive values only)

aa2<-gam(UQdata~s(MudUQ,bs="ps", k=15) ,family=Gamma(link=log),data=Antho)
xmin <- ceiling(min(Antho$MudUQ[Antho$Bin==1]))
xmax <- floor(max(Antho$MudUQ[Antho$Bin==1]))
Mudnew <- seq(from=xmin, to=xmax, by=0.1)
**Error in if (del == 0 && to == 0) return(to) : 
                missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**
pred.dat <- data.frame(Mudnew)
names(pred.dat) <- "MudUQ"
pred.aa2 <- data.frame(predict.gam(aa2, pred.dat, se.fit=TRUE, type="response"))
pred.aa2.comb <- data.frame(pred.dat, pred.aa2)
names(pred.aa2.comb)
plot(fit ~ MudUQ, data=pred.aa2.comb, type="l", lwd=2, col=1, 
     lab="Density per 0.0132 m2", xlab="Mud content (%)")
```

Comment: I don't know why you are surprised, if you don't make your code reproducible (to such an extent that you have no idea *which package you are using*!). How do you know this *really* worked before and wasn't dependent upon some local conditions?

Comment: I appreciate your help Gavin- I did state: "After loading mgcv and running the below model" at the start of my initial question.. Nonetheless, I'm trying to answer a question in my post-grad thesis with minimal R coding expertise (obviously) and under serious time constraints - so your assistance is greatly appreciated. I know it really worked before because it produced models for a number of species on separate occasions - does that satisfy code being reproducible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the wrong package? Both the **mgcv** and **gam** packages have function `s()`, but only the former's takes a `bs` and a `k` argument to influence the basis functions.

For example, I can reproduce the error using `gam::gam()`:

```
> require("gam")
> data(kyphosis)
> gam(Kyphosis ~ s(Age, k = 4, bs = "ps") + Number, family = binomial, 
+     data=kyphosis, trace = TRUE)
Error in s(Age, k = 4, bs = "ps") : unused arguments (k = 4, bs = "ps")
> gam(Kyphosis ~ s(Age) + Number, family = binomial, data=kyphosis, trace = TRUE)
GAM s.wam loop 1: deviance = 66.42095 
GAM s.wam loop 2: deviance = 63.77252 
GAM s.wam loop 3: deviance = 63.25199 
GAM s.wam loop 4: deviance = 63.13399 
GAM s.wam loop 5: deviance = 63.11016 
GAM s.wam loop 6: deviance = 63.10748 
GAM s.wam loop 7: deviance = 63.10727 
GAM s.wam loop 8: deviance = 63.10725 
GAM s.wam loop 9: deviance = 63.10725 
Call:
gam(formula = Kyphosis ~ s(Age) + Number, family = binomial, 
    data = kyphosis, trace = TRUE)

Degrees of Freedom: 80 total; 75.00002 Residual
Residual Deviance: 63.10725
```

but not with the **mgcv** package and `mgcv::gam()`:

```
> require(mgcv)
> require("mgcv")
> set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
> dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)
Gu & Wahba 4 term additive model
> b <- gam(y ~ s(x0, k = 5, bs = "ps") + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data=dat)
Loading required package: splines
```

Comment: Any idea's regarding the second error I've posted beneath the first?

Comment: Look at `xmin` and `xmax` to see if there are any odd values or `NA`s.

Comment: Yes thanks, `na.rm=TRUE` in each xmin and xmax line fixed it.

Comment: @user2673404 good, though I'd be a little concerned that you are getting `NA` now when you didn't before. Make sure you check *why* this is happening & understand where these come from. Could indicate an issue way back down the line or it could just be a new rogue data point.